# Add a TPM to a board

Tags: tpm, physical-security

I am to release a design based on an Atheros SoC. I want to additionally secure the system. So I'm looking into adding a TPM to the motherboard's design, or using some USB/serial security token. I know very little about this topic. Where would I start?

Comment: just to clarify are you designing a board or using an existing board?

Comment: Also, the [Trusted Computing Group](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/trusted_platform_module_tpm_summary) has a lot of good resources for understanding TPMs and also has a Developers resource section that may prove useful.

Comment: If the SoC supports it, you could also consider using a TrustZone based TPM. Depending on your scope/budget.

Comment: Have you looked at the wikipedia entry on this?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module